# CORS on AzureWebSites (same origin?)

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service

CORS says that:

> A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, and port) than its own origin.

That been said, look at this scenario. I have two apps deployed on the azure.

- `https://myApp.azurewebsites.net` .NET FW app that has a Angular client.
- `https://myMicroservice.azurewebsites.net` .NET CORE API.

Since both apps are in the same site (origin) `azurewebsites` does that mean that I don't need to configure `CORS`?

***Note***: I already have configured CORS on the .NET CORE app to allow the `https://myApp.azurewebsites.net` origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the `same origin` means that `xxx.azurewebsites.net` should be the same one(as well as `xxx`).

So in your case, you need to enable `CORS`. Otherwise, the access is not allowed.

Comment: Nice, thank you for your response! Is this common to people down vote a question on this topic? I think I created a clear and decent question to ask, don't understand why the down vote...

Comment: Some people think it's not a code-related question:(.